# Additive function on normed linear space are linear if continuous

Tags: normed-spaces

Is it true:
Suppose $T$ is an additive function on normed linear space $X$ to a normed linear space $Y$, i.e. $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y)$ for all $x,y\in X$

and $T$ continuous at a point. Would $T$ be linear i.e. $T(ax) = aT(x)$ for all $x\in X$?

I have proved for case when normed linear space is R but is it true for all normed linear spaces

Comment: What is the codomain of $T$?

Comment: @FrankLu a normed linear space

Comment: In the case of complex normed spaces $T$ can be linear or antilinear, I guess.

Comment: @JankoBracic what do you mean by antilinear?

Comment: $T(\alpha x+\beta y)=\overline{\alpha} Tx+\overline{\beta} Ty$

Comment: Can we prove it will only be of these two types either linear or antilinear @JankoBracic

Comment: Maybe the following is of some help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation